# SCP command works, but I cannot find downloaded file

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, putty, scp

I used Putty to remote into my Raspberry Pi.  I am trying to scp a file from another computer. The scp command works, and it shows that file is downloaded, however, I cannot find anything on my raspberry pi.

Anyone can help me solve this?

Thanks!

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYSW3.png)

Answer (score 2):

You have downloaded that file to /Documents rather than ~/Documents. Change your scp command to:

```
scp pi@155.198.134.5:test.txt ~/Documents
```

and you will be able to find it in your documents directory. Alternatively move the already downloaded file to your home directory with:

```
mv /Documents ~/Documents/test.txt
```

Comment: Oh that's it. Thank you very much.